# How can I handle Ctrl+C in a Windows CE console application?

Tags: winapi, console, signals, windows-ce

I need to make some clean up before closing my application, but `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` doesn't seem to be available for Windows CE console applications.

Is there any alternative method for handling `Ctrl+C` in Windows CE 6?

Comment: Any chance you can instead go with the approach of "disabling" Control+C from killing your app?  This I/O control might do the trick for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931517.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to do some clean up before closing the application, not to prevent the application to be killed.

Answer (score 5):

According to Microsoft's documentation, on Windows CE 3.0 and up, the `DeviceIoControl` function called with the `IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER` control code will install a Ctrl+C handler on Windows CE. I haven't tried it out myself yet, but something like this "should" work:

```
DWORD ignore;
DeviceIoControl(
    _fileno(stdout),                    // handle to the console
    IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER,   // Tell Win CE to set the console Ctrl+C handler
    (LPVOID)consoleHandler,             // pointer to the signal handler
    sizeof(consoleHandler),             // size of the pointer
    NULL,                               // output buffer not needed
    0,                                  // zero output buffer size
    &ignore,                            // no data will be put into the output buffer so we don't need its size
    NULL);                              // not an asynchronous operation - don't need to provide async info
```

where `consoleHandler` is of course your Ctrl+C handler.

Docs:

- [DeviceIoControl (CE 7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee481660.aspx)
- [IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER (CE .NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906161.aspx)

Headers needed:

- `Console.h`
- `winbase.h` (usually included through windows.h).

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on Windows Embedded Compact 7. The Ctrl+C and the "window closed" events are both catched.

1. Create a Win32 event.
2. Pass that event to DeviceIoControl() using the IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCEVENT, and given the console handle (e.g., _fileno(stdout)). That event will be signaled when Ctrl+C is typed, or the console window is closed.
3. Create a thread that waits on the Win32 event becoming signaled, and when it becomes so, calls your Ctrl+C handler or performs your cleanup, and probably exits the program.

Notice that IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER has been deprecated and DeviceIoControl() fails when it is given that IOCTL code.