# How can I handle console closing in a Windows CE?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-ce, console-application

I have a Win32 C++ console application running in Window CE 6.0 that contains a number of continuously running threads.  Occasionally there is a need to stop the application, and I would like that to happen in a controlled manner.  One method of doing this would be to simply monitor the console window, and if it closes then stop the process.  Unfortunately [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does not appear to be part of the Win32 api for Windows CE 6.0.  Does anyone know how I can detect that the console is closing in a Win32 C++ program running in CE?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for Ctrl-C by calling [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898288.aspx) with [`IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906161.aspx).  Use [`_fileno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms860492.aspx)`(stdout)` for the hDevice parameter.

I don't think there's any way to get notified for any other "close" mechanism.

Comment: I thought that IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER was a .Net call.  Is that available from a Win32 application?

Comment: should work, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366879/how-can-i-handle-ctrlc-in-a-windows-ce-console-application

Comment: It's most defintely *not* a .NET call - it's an IOCTL value that you send to DeviceIoControl which is a pure Win32 API call.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on Windows Embedded Compact 7. The Ctrl+C and the "window closed" events are both catched.

1. Create a Win32 event.
2. Pass that event to DeviceIoControl() using the IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCEVENT, and given the console handle (e.g., _fileno(stdout)). That event will be signaled when Ctrl+C is typed, or the console window is closed.
3. Create a thread that waits on the Win32 event becoming signaled, and when it becomes so, calls your Ctrl+C handler or performs your cleanup, and probably exits the program.

Notice that IOCTL_CONSOLE_SETCONTROLCHANDLER has been deprecated and DeviceIoControl() fails when it is given that IOCTL code.